# upgrade from Artifactory 2.3.3.1

Tags: upgrade, artifactory

As in the subject, we are currently stuck at very (!) old version 2.3.3.1. We must upgrade to the latest (or a least a much more recent) version.

I suspect I'll need a few steps to make such a version leap.

Please give me any pointers you may find useful. This has landed on me, and I've never worked with Artifactory before.

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected, there are several versions you'll have to go through, like 3.9.x.
You can find more info [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF3X/Upgrading+Artifactory) and [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-UpgradingfromVersion3.x)

Comment: Many thanks, your URLs are right on the money for me.

Answer (score 0):

Following the directions above:

I have taken us to 2.6.7 as a necessary upgrade step, and today I worked on moving to 3.9.2 as a next necessary step.

I have followed the official instructions from https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF3X/Upgrading+Artifactory

The "empty" 3.9.2 worked fine of course, so I proceeded with the copy of the filestore and then the import of the System export. The Export had been done as instructed, i.e. with Content excluded, and nothing else excluded.

The import finished but with 99 errors. These were of these three types:

1. A file missing from the export. In all cases, the export contained a folder with the same name as the file but with a ".artifactory-metadata" appended to its name. So for example instead of

/BACKUP_DISK/ARTIFACTORY/20200402.192450/repositories/jboss-releases-cache/jboss/jboss-j2ee/4.2.0.GA/jboss-j2ee-4.2.0.GA.pom

...in the export there was this folder:

/BACKUP_DISK/ARTIFACTORY/20200402.192450/repositories/jboss-releases-cache/jboss/jboss-j2ee/4.2.0.GA/jboss-j2ee-4.2.0.GA.pom.artifactory-metadata/

...containing two files, artifactory-file.xml and artifactory.stats.xml

2. Errors about failure to import a file because "MD5 value 'null' is not a valid checksum"
3. Errors about failure to import file because " Artifact rejected: The repository 'codehaus-cache' is blacked out and cannot serve artifact"

The last disturbing thing is that the new installation in the Home page states that there are half as many artifacts as in the 2.6.7 installation. I wonder if some kind of merging/relabelling has been done, and I should not worry about that.

I'd be grateful for any clues on the above.